# Cucumber rhtml eport is not generating in valid format in selenium cucumber

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm trying to generate my reports in html format in **maven cucumber html report**. I'm able to generate cucumber json and cucumber pretty html report, but the issue is the generated report is not in an html format and it doesn't have any data. Can somebody please help me to solve this issue.

#### Maven pom dependency and plugin

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0</version>
</dependency>

 <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>execution</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <projectName>CucumberReport</projectName>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                                <!-- <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput> -->
                                    <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                                <!-- <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting> -->
                                <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
                                <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

#### TestRunner Class

```
@CucumberOptions(features="testFeature",glue= {"stepDefinitions"}
,plugin={"html:target/site/cucumber-pretty","json:target/cucumber.json"},monochrome=true)
public class TestRunnerTestNG extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{
```

#### generated report file format

[image: generated report format]

Comment: Im unsure if this will help but all the docs show the export of plugin like so:
`{"pretty","json:target/cucumber.json","html:target/site/cucumber-pretty"}` what if you change your runner class to:
`@CucumberOptions(features="testFeature",glue= {"stepDefinitions"}
,plugin={"pretty","json:target/cucumber.json","html:target/site/cucumber-pretty"},monochrome=true)
public class TestRunnerTestNG extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{`

Comment: sure,i will check that

Comment: i tried now but same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found my answer here 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtEp5r6ilKE

and update pom plugin like here not dependency
https://github.com/damianszczepanik/maven-cucumber-reporting

hope it help to others.